# Extracting string before the quotations

Tags: python, extract, quotes

I am trying to parse a pdf in python and extract string in quotations. I am able to extract the text in quotations but I also want to extract the name before the quotation starts.
For example:
Consider this

Ziblatt, Daniel. 2004. "Rethinking the Origins of Federalism: Puzzle, Theory, and Evidence from Nineteenth-Century Europe,"

I am able to extract everything quotations but I want the name to be extracted as well .
This is the code I am using.. Please help

```
def quotes(x):
    quoted = re.compile('"[^"]*"')
    for value in quoted.findall(x):
        print value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing data before a double-quote should work:

```
def quotes(x):
    quoted = re.compile('(.+)"[^"]+"')
    for value in quoted.findall(x):
        print value.strip()
```

I get this ouput:

```
>>> quotes(text)
'Ziblatt, Daniel. 2004.'
```